How to satisfy find_package() inside CMakeLists.txt?
I am trying to use sdbus-cpp library. To use the documentation says you have to use find_package(). I undestand that this command searches for sdbus-c++ on the user's system.
I, however, want this library to be built together with my own source. Thus the question: how do I satisfy the find_package() inside my own CMakeLists.txt?
The library author does provide instructions on how to build and install the library, but I don't the use of my own library to be forced to type extra commands in the terminal. I guess I have to add Find*.txt file or add install() command but I couldn't make them work...

As Roman suggested in his answer, find_package is probably not what you want in your case, since you want to build the project with your own source-code (not before). I would upload the project you want to build together with your own source and use FetchContent to fetch and include it. Alternatively you could simply copy the project into your main project directory and include the top level CMakeLists.txt in your main project.

You can use FetchContent for this. For example:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(TestSdbus)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(sdbus
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp.git
  GIT_TAG        master
)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "" ON)
option(BUILD_EXAMPLES "" OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(sdbus)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable(test_sdbus ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(test_sdbus sdbus-c++)

Note that this library has an external dependency on pkj-config and libsystemd-dev system packages.
